# techique to avoid multiple loops in different areas of same page using same model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC view have strongly typed List as model. As per page template design, to display data from Model I need to do multiple loops. Situation is I can't put every thing in a single loops because some containing tags (for example div, section and tables) are to be displayed just once.

I m looping in top of page, multiple loops in body and in footer. Model is search result and in itself would be heavy and dynamic, on average it will have approximately 250 records. 250 records and looping it for 10 to 15 times is much resource consumption.

I m sure this is not a new challenge but wondering how it is dealt. Can you please guide me what can be done to make situation better. Currently it is server side model binding.

Edit: Adding a snap short of my template design, please note it is just a part of design there are many other parts as well.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are probably doing too much on this page ... remember SRP ... why are you looping the same data multiple times? kinda feels like redundancy/duplication ...

Comment: @scartag, it is page requirement. It is a search result page and I need to display search results with different headings.

Comment: Hard to tell from just an image, but looks like you are only displaying 4 items per page so why do you need to loop through 250? (your model should be just a collection with the 4 items you want to display). If you use ajax to get the 4 objects based on the search criteria (or the next/previous button) and return it as JSON, you would only need one loop (just update the relevant contents of the table cell with the returned data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to design I have to do multiple loops I was trying to avoid it. If some one has same issue would be good to use some JS binding library.

Answer (score 2):

Looping 250 records 10 to 15 times is not a resource problem.

The list doesn't contain the actual records, it only contains references to the records, so getting the records from the list is not a resource heavy operation at all.

If you actually need data from the list in 10 to 15 places in the page, then what you have is fine.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your views. But still issue is looping 15 times on same data records is expensive and I want to avoid it. Any suggest on this end please ?

Comment: @user576510: Why do you think that it is expensive? The bottle neck here is always going to be the network transfer, so if you are using one loop or 15 loops to generate the same result will have negligible impact on the performance. Anyhow, to suggest any improvements, you would need to show exactly what you are doing in your code.

Comment: since view (html) is such a big, it will hard to follow the code. I m adding screen short of design. Please have a loop at my edit and share your thoughts.

Comment: @user576510: Hard to say anything from just a design, but it doesn't seem like you can reduce the number of loops in any way that is useful. If you are looping out four records from the result, then maybe your model should be an object that encapsulates the list and has another list with just those four items. That won't make much of a performance difference, but it will make the code cleaner.